# Jquery add more with html object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make addmore functionality with jQuery html object below is the code.

```
var addmorehtml = $("<div><div class='btndiv'><label>Category Name : </label><input type='text' name='catname[]'></div></div>");
var  HTML = addmorehtml;
var clickcount = 1;

$('button#addmore').on('click', function(){
    HTML.find('div.btndiv').wrap("<div id='so_" + clickcount + "'></div>");
    $("<button class='removeme' onClick='removeMe(\"" + clickcount +"\")'>Remove Me</button>").insertBefore(HTML.find('div.btndiv'));
    $('div#result').append(HTML.html());  

    /* Why do I need to do this two steps  START */ 
    HTML.find('div.btndiv').unwrap("<div id='so_" + clickcount + "'></div>");   
    HTML.find('button.removeme').remove();
    /* END */
    clickcount++;  
});
```

If I don't unwrap the added html at the end, it keeps on adding to new elements created. I know there are many ways of doing add more but if I want to go with this what modification in existing code should be done so that I don't need to perform those those steps as mentioned in between comments.

Any help would be appreciated.

Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/bhingarde/Lav7Lt7o/13/

Comment: look at the resulting html without those 2 lines. it is pretty evident. The `unwrap` line is preventing id duplication and the `remove` line is preventing multiple remove buttons to be in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

JSFIDDLE DEMO -> http://jsfiddle.net/Lav7Lt7o/15/

As shown below, add the html blob directly to the `div#result` instead of breaking it.

```
var clickcount = 1;

$('button#addmore').on('click', function() {

    var addmorehtml = $("<div id='so_" + clickcount + "'><button class='removeme' onclick='removeMe(" + clickcount + ")'>Remove Me</button><div class='btndiv'><label>Category Name : </label><input type='text' name='catname[]'></div></div>");

    $('div#result').append(addmorehtml);

    clickcount++;

});

function removeMe(id) {
    $('div#so_' + id).remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSFIDDLE DEMO -> http://jsfiddle.net/Lav7Lt7o/18/

You just wanted a modification to your existing code but I wanted to give you another answer which is better than the modification answer I have posted before this.

The below answer removes the usage of `clickcount`and uses event delegation to capture the remove event.

```
$('button#addmore').on('click', function() {    
    var addmorehtml = $("<div id='so'><button class='removeme'>Remove Me</button><div class='btndiv'><label>Category Name : </label><input type='text' name='catname[]'></div></div>");
    $('div#result').append(addmorehtml);
});

$(document).on('click', '.removeme', function() {
    $(this).parent('#so').remove();
});
```